# .htaccess 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

This is my HTML file:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<h1>This is the HTML file.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>This is the PHP file.</h1>";
?>
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?test.html$ test.php [L]
```

When i load test.html got error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /modul-1-froland/rewrite_test/test.html on this server.

instead of loading my test.php file. Any idea how can i fix it? Working in MAMP (http://localhost/modul-1-froland/rewrite_test/test.html)

Comment: May I know what you're trying to do and what's that you're trying with . htaccess?

Comment: its just a simple example, i want to learning .htaccess files how working. at the beginning with this simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule says that your URL must start with `test.html` with an optional `/` at the start, however you're accessing `/modul-1-froland/rewrite_test/test.html` which does not start with `test.html`

Change it to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule test.html$ test.php [L]
```

to match all URLs which end with `test.html`

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` in your server root? Also is mod_rewrite enabled? Does your site config allow overrides? Also check http://htaccess.mwl.be/ to run quick tests on .htaccess rules.

Comment: .htaccess file in my folder (where is test.php and test.html). Tested in the site and seems like working, but in my localhost dont. Maybe mod_rewrite disabled